# Pattern rule in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -O2

ROOT_DIR := $(shell dirname $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
TEST_DIR = $(ROOT_DIR)/test

TEST_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(TEST_DIR)/*.c)
TEST_OBJECTS := $(TEST_SOURCES:.c=.o)

.PHONY: test
test: $(TEST_OBJECTS)

$(TEST_DIR)/%.o: $(TEST_DIR)/%.h
    @echo "here"

$(TEST_DIR)/%.h: $(TEST_DIR)/%.c
    java -jar ../aceunit/generator/AceUnit.jar $(basename $<) $(ROOT_DIR)/test/test_map > $@
```

As you can see this file is compiling AceUnit test files (.c). The first step in doing so is using AceUnit's header generator, as you can see in the last rule. So I'm trying to add the header (.h) files as a dependency to object (.o) files before compiling, but it's not working. The rule you see is not matching with the `%.o` pattern, but instead running make's default build rule. If, however, I remove the dependency, the rule is matched and it echoes `here` instead. Here's how:

```
$(TEST_DIR)/%.o:
    @echo "here"
```

How is the dependency causing this? How can I fix it? I've also tried using `$($@:.o=.h)` instead of `$(TEST_DIR)/%.h`. Although the rule does match, the `$<` variable appears to be empty, but I need the matched pattern. Plus, it's not running the last rule at all, where I build the header (.h) files from the source (.c).

Comment: You can try and run make with the `-r` option to cancel all predefined rules. Also you should add the `.c` file as a dependency for the `.o` file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that make is using the builtin `.o` from `.c` rule because it's quicker than going through your `.h` rule and as such it has higher priority.

You can [cancel](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) the builtin rule simply with a `%.o: %.c` line.

At this point make will still consider the `.h` an [intermediate file](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules) and will remove it when it finishes. If this is ok with you, you're done! Otherwise, read on.

The right way to prevent deletion is to add the `.h` files to the [special target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html) `.SECONDARY`. Unfortunately, `.SECONDARY` doesn't accept pattern rules, so you'll have to create an explicit list of all the generated headers. `.PRECIOUS` accepts pattern rules, but it will keep the file even when things go wrong, which you probably don't want. Also, `.SECONDARY` without prerequisites will mark everything as secondary, which can be a viable solution if you have no intermediate targets (unfortunately `.INTERMEDIATE` won't override an empty `.SECONDARY`).

On a side note, there is good news. Having `.SECONDARY` and `.INTERMEDIATE` accept patterns is in make's [TODO list](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/TODO.private?id=798ebd241ba348748b9e9b302b9d07dbfec64e42#n88)! I bet it's going to be awesome, they've been working on it for [17 years](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/commit/TODO.private?id=4121dea6a59367b4431cbe7a3c43d74fec9fd832).