# Bypass default rule for make

Tags: c, makefile, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile several .c files through assembler:

```
%.S: %.c
        $(XCC) -S -o $@ $(XCFLAGS) -c $<

%.o: %.S
        $(XCC) -o $@ $(XCFLAGS) -c $<

test.a: test.o foo.o 
        $(LD) -o $@ $^ $(XLDFLAGS)
```

$(XCC) is a cross-compile tool.

Actually, I see:

```
cc    -c -o test0.o test0.c
cc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

Native compilation runs instead of required cross compilation. I looks like some default rule for %.c to %.o translation is used instead of described chain rule.

If I change one pattern to direct description, compilation is ok:

```
test.S: test.c
        $(XCC) -S -o $@ $(XCFLAGS) -c $<

foo.S: foo.c
        $(XCC) -S -o $@ $(XCFLAGS) -c $<

%.o: %.S
        $(XCC) -o $@ $(XCFLAGS) -c $<
```

What is wrong with pattern chain? Is it possible to disable default rule for %.o ?

Comment: to keep the temporary *.S files, add the statement:  `.PRECIOUS %.S`

Answer (score 3):

There is a default rule to generate `.o` files from `.c` files. That rule gets invoked when the first makefile is used.

You could add the following to the makefile to override the default rule:

```
%.o: %.c
        $(XCC) -S -o $*.S $(XCFLAGS) -c $<
        $(XCC) -o $@ $(XCFLAGS) -c $*.S
```

---

You can also use:

```
%.o: %.c
```

without any recipes under it. This will invoke the other two rules to create the .S file and the .o file from there. However, it will delete the intermediate .S file after the .o is created. To prevent the .S file from getting deleted, you can use:

```
.PRECIOUS: test.S foo.S
```

You can read more on this subject at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules.

Comment: This rebuilds the .S every time.

Comment: There is probably way to indicate to make to prefer the `%.o: %.S` rule ahead of this rule. It's worth looking up.

Comment: No such way I'm afraid. When compiling the `.o`, make will end up evaluating two rules: the builtin `.c -> .o` one, and the user-defined `.S -> .o`. Since the latter needs rule chaining (because the `.S` doesn't exist and needs to be made via `.c -> .S`), while the former has an already exisiting prerequisite, it will prefer the builtin one. See [chained rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html). BTW, patterns in `.PRECIOUS` have been a TODO for 17 years...

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your rules and just [cancel](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) the builtin rule with `%.o: %.c`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39625452/6644919).

Comment: Yes, it works. So, it is enough to add  `%.o: %.c` line to bypass described problem. Thanks a lot!